# Like con 'CH' SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, like

tengo una consulta con un like en sql server pero al hacer la consulta solo me trae productos relacionados con la 'C' y me excluye los valores con 'CH'.

Mi consulta es así:

```
select * from productos where id_producto like 'c%'.
```

¿Cómo puedo ajustar mi consulta para que me traiga valores que inicien con 'C' como con 'CH'?

Comment: o sea, tu consulta entrega todos los resultados que empiezan con la letra `c`....y `ch` empieza con `c`

Comment: Pero esos valores no me los trae por ejemplo me traería cadenas, pero chalupa no.

Comment: pero es que no debería pasar eso, seguro que estás usando la columna correcta?, es `id_producto` la columna que contiene el nombre del producto?

Comment: creo que el problema es la columna ... debería ser la columna de nombre .... y si la letra `c` es parte de la segunda palabra no va a encontrarla ...  puede mejorar tu post.

Comment: el Id del producto comienza on c me imagino, para que de un resultado

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el resultado de esta consulta? `SELECT COLLATION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'productos' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'id_producto'`

Comment: Me trae este valor: Traditional_Spanish_CI_AS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando una intercalación (`collation` en inglés) que toma el dígrafo `ch` como una letra distinta. Lo mismo pasa con `l` y `ll`. Para corregir esto, tienes distintas opciones.

La más completa de todas es cambiar la estructura de toda tu base de datos para usar una intercalación más adecuada a las convenciones modernas del idioma como `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. Este es un trabajo complejo porque debes cambiarlo en las bases de datos del sistema, las bases de datos de usuario y las columnas ya existentes. Sin embargo, a largo plazo puede resultar mejor.

Otra opción, es simplemente indicar el uso de la intercalación en esa consulta. Pero esto puede generar que tu código se vaya llenando de esas instrucciones.

```
SELECT *
FROM Productos 
WHERE id_producto LIKE 'c%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
```

La última opción, también resulta compleja a largo plazo, ya que sería agregar una segunda condición que incluya ambas "letras". Pero eso agrega más complejidad a la hora de escribir código usando variables.

```
SELECT *
FROM Productos 
WHERE (id_producto LIKE 'c%'
OR id_producto LIKE 'ch%');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funciono, dios te lo pague.